# conversion of a gbff file to a gff file

Tags: sequence-annotation, gff

I want to get the annotations in gff format for a assembled genome. But for some species there is no available annotation in gff format in NCBI but only in gbff format. And I don’t know how to convert a gbff file to a gff file. So, I am seeking your help. Can I have your suggestions here? Your guidence will be appreciated.

Comment: answered here: https://www.biostars.org/p/9545716/#9545750

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Is the following link be applicable?

https://github.com/Tesla-huang/Scripts/blob/master/gbff2gff.pl

Comment: https://github.com/jorvis/biocode/blob/master/gff/convert_genbank_to_gff3.py

Comment: I don't know either way (just happened to spot GenoMax's answer at Biostars)... but if either/both of those links do the trick for you, then maybe that answer was wrong and this *is* possible.